# Intersection of open sets?

Tags: real-analysis

> (a) Show that the intersection of finitely many open sets is open
>
> (b) Give an example showing that the intersection of infinitely many open sets
> may fail to be open.

(a)

1. An open set is defined as having all its points' $\epsilon$-neighborhood contained inside.
2. Assuming The intersection of finitely many open set $O_1,O_2,...,O_k$ is non-null, we have at least a point $x$ such that $x \in \bigcap_{k=1}^{n} O_k$.
3. By definition, this point $x$ has $\epsilon$-neighborhood contained in each set $O_1,O_2,...,O_k$ .
4. However, the magnitude of each $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $x$ contained in each set is specific to each set.
5. Among all the  $\epsilon$-neighborhood magnitude of $x$ contained specifically in each open-set {$\epsilon$_1,$\epsilon$_2,...,$\epsilon$_n},
6. Only the $\epsilon$ with the minimal magnitude will be contained by all the set and therefore by the intersection.

(b) I do not see here how the intersection of infinitely many open could fail to be open.

Regarding (a) Is the reasoning correct or sufficient? If this is correct, what would be a more efficient approach?

Any input for (a) or (b) is much appreciated.

Comment: Take the intersection of all open sets containing the interval $[0,1]$. It might help to find a particular sequence of nested open intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning for $(a)$ is correct, but lets look at it more closesly:

For each $i$ with $1\le i \le n$ we can find $\varepsilon_i$ such that $B_{\varepsilon_i}(x)\subset O_i$. Now, since the $\varepsilon_i$ are **finitely many**, then we can pick $\delta>0$ such that $\delta <\varepsilon_i$ for all $i$. Therefore, $B_\delta(x)\subset B_{\varepsilon_i}(x)\subset O_i$ for every $i$ and hence $B_\delta(x)\subset \bigcap_{i=1}^n O_i$.

The key is that the infimum among the $\varepsilon_i$ is $>0$ because we are considering finitely many positive numbers. Note that this fails for infinite sets of numbers, for example

$$\inf\{ 1/n: n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\}=0$$

With this in mind, it is not difficult to show that

$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (-1/n,1/n)=\{0\}$$

which is not open, and answers (b).

Comment: How do we prove it is zero?

Comment: @JosephRock As $0\in (-1/n,1/n)$ for every $n$, $0\in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (-1/n,1/n)$. Conversely, let $x\in  \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (-1/n,1/n)$. If $x>0$, by the Archimedean property there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ with $0<1/N<x$, so that $x\not\in (-1/N,1/N)$, contradiction. If $x<0$, by the same reason there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ with  $0<1/N<-x$, so that $x<-1/N$ and so $x\not\in(-1/N,1/N)$, another contradiction. By trichotomy, the only option is that $x=0$.

Comment: can it be the empty set sir?

Comment: @JosephRock No, since $0$ is in every $(-1/n,1/n)$, the intersection can't possibly be empty

Answer (score 3):

Consider the sets $(-1/n,1/n)$. Their intersection is $\{0\}$.

Comment: shouldnt the intersection be an empty set sir?