# intersection of $(-1/n,1/n)$ as n$ \to \infty$ , is it empty?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, limits, analysis

What is the intersection of the set $(-1/n, 1/n)$ as $n \to \infty$?

I got this idea of intersection from [Intersection of open sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2321769/intersection-of-open-sets), shouldnt the intersection be the empty set since a number cannot be any number since it must be both a positive and negative real number.. Some say zero is the intersection but zero is not positive nor negative, sorry for not being clear

Comment: What about $0$?

Comment: Why do you think the intersection should be empty?

Comment: "houldnt the intersection be the empty set since a number cannot be positive and negative at the same time?"  1) what does that have to do with anything and the intersection and 2) No number can be both positive and negative but there is one number that can be neither.

Comment: sorry i clarified it in the edit

Comment: zero is not a number that is both positive nor negative so it cannot be zero..

Comment: Why should the intersection consist of numbers that are both positive an negative???

Comment: @fleablood empty set can be an intersection..

Comment: What do you mean "*both* positive *nor* negative".  $0$ is *neither* positive nor negative.

Comment: @fleablood i mean it must be both, negative and positive explicitly

Comment: "empty set can be an intersection." It *can* be but it doesn't have to be..... Again... what is your thinking.  *Why* are you talking about numbers that are both positive nor negative.  Why do you think that has something to do with the intersection?  And what about $0$ which is *neither* positive nor negative.  How does that fit in?

Comment: Then, yes, there is no number that is both positive and negative.  And there are birds in the antarctic called penguins.  What does that have to do with the intersection?

Comment: 1/n is positive, -1/n is negative, to satisfy both requirements, i must have both positive and both negative, since there is no number that is positive and negative at the same time, i conclude, that this is an empty set

Comment: "any number since it must be both a positive and negative real number"  WHY????????????

Comment: There is no reason that the numbers in the  intersection need to be both.  Maybe some are positive and some are negative, and maybe $0$ is in the intersection.  There is no reason the intersection should consist of numbers that are *both*.  None if the intervals have numbers that are both.  But they *ALL*  have $0$ in them.  So $0$ *MUST* be in the intersection.

Comment: You seem to be making some assumptions for no reason.  You are assuming the intersection has only one element.  (In this case it does but in general it doesn't have to).  You seem to assume that it must have a positive element.  Why? All of the intervals have positive elements but they need not all be the same and there need not be a positive element that is in *ALL* of them.  Ditto negative. So you are making a faulty assumption that the intersection must have numbers that are both positive *and* negative.  You reason for thinking that is faulty.

Comment: the reason i say this is because, if a set has some property, then the intersection of that set must have that property too, so if a set has positive property, then the intersection of that set must be positive, which is why the positive and negative numbers have no intersection..

Comment: I think you had better understand the definition of intersection of a collection of sets and convince yourself that $0$ is an element of that intersection.

Comment: Yes all those sets contain $0$ and this property is possessed by the intersection also. Not every property of the sets will be preserved in intersection. So what you think actually works in reverse. Whatever belongs to the intersection belongs to every set of the collection.

Comment: 1) The intersection *doesn't* have to have the properties of the sets. ANd 2) The set $(-\frac 1n, \frac 1n)$ does *not* have the property that all its elements are positive and negative.  It has *some* positive elements, and some negative elements, and one element that is neither.  But it doesn't have *any* that are both.  So there is *no* reason the intersection should have elements that are both.

Comment: "if a set has some property, then the intersection of that set must have that property too" That just isn't true.  $A= \{a,b,c\}$ and $B=\{c,d,e\}$ both have the property that they have three elements.  But $A\cap B = \{c\}$ doesn't have that property.

Comment: "Whatever belongs to the intersection belongs to every set of the collection."  *ELEMENTS* belong.  *properties* are vague notions and the statement doesn't hold.

Answer (score 4):

Notice $0 \in (-1/n,1/n)$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore, $0 \in \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (-1/n,1/n)$. As for any other real number, consider any positive real $r$. Choose a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $1/n < r$. Then we know that $r \notin (-1/n,1/n)$. Hence, this $r$ is not in the intersection. You can perform a similar argument for a negative $r$. What you are confused about is 'at infinity' there is nothing. But that's the point - you never actually reach that infinite value, merely track what happens as you approach it. This is similar to the concept when we say $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n}=0$, even though $\{1/n\}$ never takes on zero as a value.

Answer (score 1):

There are two facts that make us need to come to the conclusion that $\cap_{n\in \mathbb N} (-\frac 1n, \frac 1n)$ must be $\{0\}$.

1) $0$ is an element of *every* $(-\frac 1n, \frac 1n)$.

and

2) If $x\ne 0$ then there is some $(-\frac 1k, \frac 1k)$ where $x \not \in (-\frac 1k, \frac 1k)$.

These two facts mean if $\cap_{n\in \mathbb N} (-\frac 1n, \frac 1n)=\{x\in \mathbb R| x\in $ *every* $ (-\frac 1n, \frac 1n)\}$, means $\cap_{n\in \mathbb N} (-\frac 1n, \frac 1n)= \{0\}$ because $0$ is the only real number that is in *every* $(-\frac 1n, \frac 1n)$

=====

So why is fact 1) true?

For any $n \in \mathbb N$ then $-\frac 1n < 0  \frac 1n$ so $0 \in (-\frac 1n, \frac 1n)$.  And that is true for *every*  $(-\frac 1n, \frac 1n)$

So why is fact 2) true?

Well if $x \ne 0$ then $|x| > 0$.  And $\frac 1{|x|} > 0$.  Now the natural number are unbounded so there is a $k$ so that $k > \frac 1{|x|}$.

So $0 < \frac 1k < |x|$.

If $x$ is positive then $-\frac 1k < \frac 1k < x$ and $x\not \in (\frac 1k,\frac 1k)$.

And if $x$ is negative then $-x < -\frac 1k < \frac 1k$ and $x\not \in (\frac 1k,\frac 1k)$

so either way $x\not \in (\frac 1k,\frac 1k)$

So 2) is true.